# Possible to extract full XML html_instructions from Google Directions API using only cell formulas?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, api, directions

I apologize in advance for my ignorance, as I'm extremely new to this. Please bear with me :)

Here's my situation (super simple):

I have a spreadsheet with a cell to enter origin, a cell to enter destination, and a cell to determine the transportation mode. I've successfully used WEBSERVICE to generate the XML response, and FILTERXML to pull out the "//html_instructions" piece. My issue, as you probably expect, is that the WEBSERVICE cell doesn't include the full string, and the FILTERXML formula only retrieves the first step in the directions. Ideally I'd love to return the full text string including all steps in the directions.

Is there ANY way to make this work without going the JSON or VBA route?

If not, is there a relatively simple solution to this?

Comment: Have you sample data that you can post? Are you asking if there is a way to parse strings and/or combine data from two strings in excel?

Comment: No, the issue is that the WEBSERVICE formula seems to generate a string with just part of the directions, not all of them (may be a cell character constraint?). The FILTERXML function works great, but it's only finding the first step of the directions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Alt + D, D, W` import the page into a new sheet and pick up the data via `Sheet2!A3` on your main sheet.

Comment: Interesting, this looks promising...

Right now my WEBSERVICE formula looks like this:
=WEBSERVICE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="&$G$5&"&destination="&$G$6&"&key="&$D$2&"&mode="&$D$8&"")

Where G5 is my origin coordinates, G6 is my destination coordinates, D8 is my mode of transport, and D2 is my API key.

Is there a way for me to automatically create a web query with this specific URL when a user changes the values?